# DX: Cannot generate password for additional users

Tags: salesforcedx

I have a script used weekly to create a scratch org used by a few users for shared config activities (we have not transitioned our non-developer, config only BAs to using the full DX toolset yet).  This script creates a scratch org, installs a managed package, adds a couple of users (`force:user:create`), pushes source, and assigns permission sets to the added users.

I also generate passwords for the users.  For some reason today I cannot; I get "ERROR:  INVALID_HEADER_TYPE."  I was able to generate password for the default user:

```
sfdx force:user:password:generate --targetusername "test-xxxxxxxxxxxx@example.com"
```

This worked fine.  But doing the same for an added user:

```
sfdx force:user:password:generate --targetusername "1535382992600_test-xxxxxxxxxxxx@example.com"
```

produces the error.  `force:user:password:generate` doesn't support `--verbose` (I tried) but I did try the `--json` option:

```
{
    "message": "INVALID_HEADER_TYPE", 
    "status": 1, 
    "stack": "INVALID_AUTH_HEADER: INVALID_HEADER_TYPE
    at HttpApi.getError (/Users/jclark/.local/share/sfdx/client/node_modules/jsforce/lib/http-api.js:250:13)
    at /Users/jclark/.local/share/sfdx/client/node_modules/jsforce/lib/http-api.js:95:22
    at tryCallOne (/Users/jclark/.local/share/sfdx/client/node_modules/promise/lib/core.js:37:12)
    at /Users/jclark/.local/share/sfdx/client/node_modules/promise/lib/core.js:123:15
    at flush (/Users/jclark/.local/share/sfdx/client/node_modules/asap/raw.js:50:29)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:131:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)", 
    "name": "INVALID_AUTH_HEADER", 
    "warnings": [ ]
}
```

I can find no other info about this error.  The JSON implies an auth issue, but other DX commands work fine (e.g., `force:org:open` successfully logs me in as the default user.)  This script worked a week ago.  `sfdx update` reports, "already on latest version: 6.29.0-0a2482692c."  What is the source of this error?

**Update:** I'm running Mac OS 10.13.6 (17G65).  Relevant version info:

```
> $ sfdx plugins --core           
@salesforce/plugin-generator 0.0.10 (core)
@salesforce/sfdx-trust 1.0.8 (core)
builtins 1.0.0 (core)
salesforcedx 43.12.0 (core)

> $ sfdx version       
sfdx-cli/6.29.0-0a2482692c (darwin-x64) node-v8.9.4

> $ node --version                       
v10.6.0
```

Comment: Can you tell me what OS you are using?  Also, what version of the toolbelt plugin are you using?  I ask, because I can't duplicate this using Mac OSX and CLI version sfdx-cli/6.29.0 (darwin-x64) node-v10.4.0 with salesforcedx 43.12.0 plugin version.

Comment: @DaveCarroll I've updated the post with version info

Comment: And you get the error when you run the password:generate command, correct?

Comment: @DaveCarroll Correct, the example `sfdx force:user:password:generate` above produces only "ERROR:  INVALID_HEADER_TYPE." as output.

Comment: This is odd. I wonder if something in the cached credentials may be corrupted.  If can MOVE the stuff in the hidden .sfdx folder to another location and try the steps again and it works, then corruption might be the cause.  Without being able to reproduce this behavior I'm not sure we can find the cause.

Comment: If you run the script again, does it work?

Comment: @Amphro Ran the script again, same issue in new org.

Comment: @DaveCarroll Should I move the stuff in <project>/.sfdx or ~/.sfdx?

Answer (score 0):

To generate password for secondary users, you have to put them in the --onbehalfof parameter. E.g.:

sfdx force:user:generate:password -u  -o

You can do it for multiple secondary users at once by separating their usernames with commas.

To make it verbose, use "--loglevel trace" or "--loglevel debug"